# StackOverflowError in tycho build

Tags: eclipse-rcp, tycho

I am getting a `StackOverflowError` in my Tycho build. I have tried using the debug flag (-X) but this does not show any useful information at the point of error.

```
constituent[38]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.8.5/lib/wagon-file-3.5.1.jar
constituent[39]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.8.5/lib/wagon-http-3.5.1-shaded.jar
constituent[40]: file:/C:/apache-maven-3.8.5/lib/wagon-provider-api-3.5.1.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.scanIPv4Address(URI.java:3413)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseIPv4Address(URI.java:3453)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseServer(URI.java:3355)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3276)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3218)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3174)
        at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623)
        at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:904)
        at java.base/java.net.URI.resolve(URI.java:1089)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.SharedHttpCacheStorage$CacheLine.getRedirect(SharedHttpCacheStorage.java:440)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.SharedHttpCacheStorage.getCacheEntry(SharedHttpCacheStorage.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.SharedHttpCacheStorage.getCacheEntry(SharedHttpCacheStorage.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.remote.SharedHttpCacheStorage.getCacheEntry(SharedHttpCacheStorage.java:111)
```

I'm using Tycho 3.0.1.

Are there any other debugging flags that I could use to get more information?

Comment: you might get more feedback on github - https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/issues

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example for Tycho 3.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @howlger See my answer below. Would you still like the example? Do you think it would be useful to anyone?

Comment: @paul Can you reproduce the `StackOverflowError` only with the target platform from your answer by doing a Maven build with Tycho 3.0.2 (not 3.0.1) only for the target platform? If so, [report it to Tycho](https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/issues) and update your answer with the link to the issue.

Comment: @howlger sorry for the delay. Here is demo of the problem: https://github.com/pramsden/tycho-stackoverflow.git. I will now report it to Tycho...

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/pramsden/tycho-stackoverflow/blob/c691ca4276f09fe9c8a2be989112d1cf8f8e4429/sandbox/pom.xml#L15) the target platform is included as Maven module (which is fine), but via the [parent POM](https://github.com/pramsden/tycho-stackoverflow/blob/c691ca4276f09fe9c8a2be989112d1cf8f8e4429/sandbox/pom.xml#L7-L12) the same [target platform is included](https://github.com/pramsden/tycho-stackoverflow/blob/main/sandbox/releng/configuration/pom.xml#L102-L104) another time. Maybe including the target platform in both ways causes it.

Comment: Just having a parent POM would be simpler that includes the target platform first, then the bundles, then the features, then the test features and finally the product(s), all of them as POM-less or not POM-less Maven modules. For example, as I did it [here](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/ea6960e6ee6c31ef96ec12c34d8f94e7ab0e40dd/pom.xml#L31-L36).

Comment: @howlger I simplified as you suggested but there is unfortunately no change to the final outcome

Comment: The same target is still included in two ways [here](https://github.com/pramsden/tycho-stackoverflow/blob/0f4ae0f5c2c81ea0f8a937b8c1bf4e9276be0819/sandbox/pom.xml#L10) and [here](https://github.com/pramsden/tycho-stackoverflow/blob/0f4ae0f5c2c81ea0f8a937b8c1bf4e9276be0819/sandbox/pom.xml#L129-L131). Does deleting [this](https://github.com/pramsden/tycho-stackoverflow/blob/0f4ae0f5c2c81ea0f8a937b8c1bf4e9276be0819/sandbox/pom.xml#L129-L131) help?

Comment: @howlger I deleted the section that you suggested but then no dependencies are loaded (`org.eclipse.ui` not found). I replaced the section with `<target><artifact>` as you have in your project but this resulted in the stackoverflow again.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an issue in the Tycho project: https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/issues/2358